# Laravel 5.4: how to iterate through request array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

My request data represents an array of new and existing items. I'm trying to through this array to update and create items.

This is how I retrieve the array:

```
$userInput = $request->all();
foreach( $userInput['items'] as $key=>&$item){
```

Later in the code I update an existing item:

```
$updateItem = Item::find($item['id']);
$updateItem->number = $item['number'];
$updateItem->save();
```

But `$item['number']` seems to contain old input from previous updates and not the value I entered last time.

How can I loop through request data in Laravel ?

This is the whole code as I run it (want to get rid of confusion):

```
$userInput = $request->all();
// checking $userInput here
// I can see the new value in the array

foreach( $userInput['items'] as $key=>$item){
  if($item['delete'] == 1) {
    Item::where('order_id',$order->id)
      ->where('id',$item['id'])
      ->delete();
  } else {
    if(empty($item['id'])) {
    } else {
      $updateItem = Item::find($item['id']);
      $updateItem->number = $item['id'];
      $updateItem->save();
    }
  }
}
```

This is an input from html (just to show I checked the form also, the data comes just fine):

```
<input id="basicItemNumber-31" class="form-control" name="items[31][number]" placeholder="Unique number" value="31" type="text">
```

Comment: Don't pass the `$item` by reference in the `for` as you can get unexpected behaviour. i.e use `$item` *not* `&$item`

Comment: remove this  & .it will work

Comment: I updated my question, passing by value still gives me the same result.

Comment: This works `$updateItem->number = $request->input("items.$key.number");` don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that somewhere inside your `for` you've inadvertently changed the value of your underling `$item` as you pass it by reference (using the `&` before the variable name.)

It's considered bad practice by some or most people as it can lead to "unexpected" behaviour, For example. take the sample code below that loops through an `array` of `$items` twice once by reference and once by value.

```
<?php

$items = ['one','two','three'];

foreach ($items as &$item) {
    //do nothing.
}

foreach ($items as $item) {
    //do nothing again.
}

var_dump($items);

//outputs

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [2]=>
  &string(3) "two"
}
```

Comment: I see that pass by reference sign was misleading. Sorry about that. I was out of bright ideas so I was trying all the stupid ones I could think of and accidently left it when writing the question. Originally I was passing $item by value and still had this problem.

Comment: All I can suggest then is you `dd($item['number'])` and check it's what you expect it to be. and work out from there.

Comment: To be honest that's where I stopped before asking. :) I just thought there's some magic in laravel that I can't comprehend. Anyway, dd gives me the right value. And! if I do something like `$updateItem->number = 999;` It saves correctly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this as it will keep your scope local:

```
$request['items']->each(function($item, $key) use ($order) {
    if ($item->delete) {
        Item::where('order_id',$order->id)
              ->where('id',$item['id'])
              ->delete();
    } else {
        if (!empty($item['id'])) {
            $updateItem = Item::find($item['id']);
            $updateItem->number = $item['id'];
            $updateItem->save();
        }
    }
});
```